# Hadith from Tarikh Baghdad

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

I do not have the mentioned source, is the following hadith mentioned elsewhere?

> Adi ibn Artah reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be
>   upon him, said, “Verily, Allah has angels whose limbs shudder from
>   fear of him. No angel among them sheds a tear from his eye but that it
>   falls upon another angel glorifying Allah. There are angels in
>   prostration since Allah created the heavens and the earth. They have
>   not raised their heads, nor will they raise them until the Day of
>   Resurrection. There are those bowing who have not raised their heads,
>   nor will they raise them until the Day of Resurrection. There are
>   those praying in rows who have not dispersed their rows, nor will they
>   disperse them until the Day of Resurrection. Thus, on the Day of
>   Resurrection, their Almighty Lord will appear before them, they will
>   look upon him and they will say: Glory be to you! We have not
>   worshiped you as you deserve to be worshiped!”
>
> Source: Tārīkh Baghdād 6704
>
> Grade: Hasan (fair) according to Ibn Kathir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is in other books, but not in the major books of hadith. You can find it in (among other books):

- [Ma'ārij al-Qabūl](https://archive.org/stream/WAQ25960/25960#page/n332/mode/1up), pp. 333
- [Lawami' al-Anhār al-Bahiyya](http://ia802706.us.archive.org/28/items/lawme3/labsaa2.pdf) pp. 248-249
- [Al-Budūr as-Sāfira](https://archive.org/stream/albodoursafira/bodour#page/n615/mode/1up) pp. 616

Not in major books of hadith, though.